# O que é o Bônus de associação, e quando ele é recebido?

Tags: suporte, reputação

O que é o Bônus de associação e quando ele é recebido?

Answer (score 9):

Citando um trecho da [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> Se for um usuário experiente da rede Stack Exchange com 200 ou mais pontos de reputação em pelo menos um site, você receberá um bônus inicial de reputação de +100 pontos para superar as restrições básicas de novo usuário. Isso acontecerá automaticamente em todos os sites atuais do Stack Exchange onde você tiver uma conta e em qualquer outro site Stack Exchange no momento que fizer log-in.

Comment: Em outras palavras, é um reconhecimento de que você já sabe como funciona o software da rede [se] e permite já entrar comentando e fazendo upvotes em qualquer outro site.